# "Scan Response" not available in advertisementData

Tags: ios, core-bluetooth

I have a configuration problem with a BLE 112 module: I cannot display the content of the scan response.

I am trying to access it thru the advertisementData dictionary of the method:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSLog(@"advertData: %@", advertisementData); 
}
```

I use the code given as an exemple by BlueGiga: ["BGScript": custom_advertisement - Custom advertisement packet creation](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/entries/23130518--BGScript-custom-advertisement-Custom-advertisement-packet-creation)
Here is the URL for the zip file [custom_advertisement.zip](https://bluegiga.zendesk.com/attachments/token/5zoq1ij3x213xhb/?name=custom_advertisement.zip)

Here is what I receive in advertisementData:

```
adv: {
    kCBAdvDataIsConnectable = 1;
    kCBAdvDataManufacturerData = <ffffb1b2 b3>;
    kCBAdvDataTxPowerLevel = 3;
}
```

But I almost never display the content of the scan response, i.e. the local name CBAdvertisementDataLocalName, on iOS. Using a sniffer, the scan response is available, tho...

Following is the part of the .bgs script used for formatting the scan response:

```
# flags for discoverable/connectable
adv_data(0:1) = $02 # ad field length = 2 bytes
adv_data(1:1) = gap_ad_type_flags   # ad field type = 0x01 (Flags)
adv_data(2:1) = $06 # flags = 0x06, connectable/undirected

# tx power field advertisement, iOS apps may need this
adv_data(3:1) = $02 # ad field length = 2 bytes
adv_data(4:1) = gap_ad_type_txpower    # ad field type = 0x0A (TX Power)
adv_data(5:1) = $03 # TX power in dBm

# custom manufacturer
adv_data(6:1) = $06 # ad field length = 5 bytes (arbitrary, maybe more or less but minimum 3)
adv_data(7:1) = $ff # ad field type = 0xFF (Manufacturer Specific Data)
adv_data(8:1) = $ff # unknown/prototype Company Identifier Code - octet 2 
adv_data(9:1) = $ff # unknown/prototype Company Identifier Code - octet 1 
adv_data(10:1) = $b1 # custom data byte #1 (can be anything)
adv_data(11:1) = $b2 # custom data byte #2 (can be anything)
adv_data(12:1) = $b3 # custom data byte #3 (can be anything)

# -------------------------------
# build custom scan response data
# -------------------------------

# get Bluetooth MAC address of this device (NOTE: this is little-endian!)
call system_address_get()(mac_addr(0:6))

sr_data(0:1) = $13  # ad field length = 19 bytes (0x13)
sr_data(1:1) = gap_ad_type_localname_complete   # ad field type = 0x09 (Complete local name)
sr_data(2:1) = $4d  # 'M'
sr_data(3:1) = $79  # 'y'
sr_data(4:1) = $20  # ' '
sr_data(5:1) = $57  # 'W'
sr_data(6:1) = $69  # 'i'
sr_data(7:1) = $64  # 'd'
sr_data(8:1) = $67  # 'g'
sr_data(9:1) = $65  # 'e'
sr_data(10:1) = $74 # 't'
sr_data(11:1) = $20 # ' '
sr_data(12:1) = (mac_addr(2:1)/$10) + 48 + ((mac_addr(2:1)/$10)/10*7) # MAC byte 4 10's digit
sr_data(13:1) = (mac_addr(2:1)&$f)  + 48 + ((mac_addr(2:1)&$f )/10*7) # MAC byte 4 1's digit
sr_data(14:1) = $3a # ':'
sr_data(15:1) = (mac_addr(1:1)/$10) + 48 + ((mac_addr(1:1)/$10)/10*7) # MAC byte 5 10's digit
sr_data(16:1) = (mac_addr(1:1)&$f)  + 48 + ((mac_addr(1:1)&$f )/10*7) # MAC byte 5 1's digit
sr_data(17:1) = $3a # ':'
sr_data(18:1) = (mac_addr(0:1)/$10) + 48 + ((mac_addr(0:1)/$10)/10*7) # MAC byte 6 10's digit
sr_data(19:1) = (mac_addr(0:1)&$f)  + 48 + ((mac_addr(0:1)&$f )/10*7) # MAC byte 6 1's digit

# set advertisement interval to 1s-2s, use all advertisement channels
# (note min/max parameters are in units of 625 uSec)
call gap_set_adv_parameters(1600, 3200, 7)

# set custom advertisement data
call gap_set_adv_data(0, 13, adv_data(0:13))

# set custom scan response data (i.e. the Device Name value)
call gap_set_adv_data(1, 20, sr_data(0:20))
```

Does anyone as an idea?

Comment: iOS will get the advertisement data "by piece". So if you may want to wait for `advertisementData` to have all the data wanted (the value for keys).

Comment: @Larme: thank you for your answer! But how do you _wait_ for advertisementData to have all the data wanted? by pausing the app for a given time in the didDiscoverPeripheral method ? By allowing duplicates and looking for new values?